# VueJs: prevent bouncing and zooming on IOS10+ with routing

Tags: javascript, ios, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

currently I am working on a Vuejs app in connection with Threejs. 3D models are to be displayed later. As a framework I use vuejs with vuetify. I use the router from vuejs.

Since I want to display 3D models, zooming across the browser is undesirable. In addition, all gestures that can be made with today's modern browsers on the smartphone must be deactivated to avoid, for example, accidentally reloading the page. I use the meta tag for this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

unfortunately it doesn't work under IOS10+. So I used InoBounce.js. This script should fix this behaviour.

This works very well on the start page, but not on any page after I have changed the route via a button. So when I click a button to get back to the start page, the script doesn't work there anymore. This is probably because the creator has not adapted it to work with vuejs.

I already tried to run the script again using a watcher when changing routes. I have rewritten the script a bit so that it no longer wants to create itself globally, but contains a method that is exported. Then I used Vuex to embed it "globally" and then run it every time the route changes. It looks like this:

```
 watch: {
   $route(to, from) {
     this.$store.state.bounceFix.fixBounce();
  },
 },
```

The debugger in the browser also indicates that the method is called at each route change. But it still works only on the main page on the first load (well, because I call it also in the "mounted" area).

So.... Am I really the only one in the internet who wants to prevent zooming in connection with a framework like vuejs? Because unfortunately I can't find much to do with it on the internet.

What is the best way to block zooming and bouncing at safari in connection with vuejs?

**UPDATE:**

I forgot an important thing:

I also had to add the following lines as a style to my  tag:

```
overflow: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

This should block gestures like "swipe to refresh".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem. The problem was that the eventlisteners in the inobounce script were set to the "window" element. I have now changed this to the "document" element. And now it works.

Means from this:

```
window.addEventListener('touchstart', handleTouchstart, supportsPassiveOption ? { passive : false } : false);
```

to this:

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', handleTouchstart, supportsPassiveOption ? { passive : false } : false);
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you try this ?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Please can you explain about the answer.